# delete Persian's Chars of string in php

Tags: php

In PHP, i have strings , similar:

```
"www.mysite.com/fa/doc/report/67571/مطذح کردنو تت";

"www.mysite.com/fa/571/نهتال اهخع";

"www.mysite.com/fa/";
```

I want if there are Persian's Chars of string, delete them.

Output:

```
www.mysite.com/fa/doc/report/67571/

www.mysite.com/fa/571/

www.mysite.com/fa/
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this code.

```
<?php
echo remove_persian("www.mysite.com/fa/doc/report/67571/مطذح کردنو تت");
function remove_persian($text)
{
    return preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9./]#', '', $text);
}
```

This will output like this:

```
www.mysite.com/fa/doc/report/67571/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex :

```
$clean = preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z\/\d\s:]', '', $url);
```